# Create XSLT from an XML to get desired XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a situation here :
Consider the following code as example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<school id="1" alias="abc" name="St.Josephs" val="">
    <teacher id="1">Rose</teacher>
    <subject>maths</subject>    
</school>
<school id="2" alias="bcd" name="" val="">
    <teacher id="2">john</teacher>
    <subject>science</subject>
</school>
<school id="3" alias="abc" name="" val="">
    <student rollno="12">sarah</student>
    <age>13</age>

</school>
<school id="4" alias="bcd" name="St.Mary's" val="">
        <student rollno="14">Rosh</student>
        <age>14</age>
</school>
```

Now here I need to design an XSLT which will create elements having data from element  where alias is abc, bcd simultaenously whose output will be something like this :

```
<Institutes>
    <group>
    <content>
            <![CDATA[
      <html>
      <head>
       <title>'Rose' is a 'Maths' teacher</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          Rose is a maths teacher for sarah in St.josephs school
      </body>
      </html>
   ]]>
    </content>
    </group>
</Institutes>
<Institutes>
    <group>
        <content>
            <![CDATA[
      <html>
      <head>
       <title>'john' is a 'science' teacher</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          john is a science teacher for Rosh in St.Mary's school
      </body>
      </html>
   ]]>
        </content>
    </group>
</Institutes>


Is there any way to achieve this..??
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to populate your input and output XML samples with some more meaningful data, rather than just say `values from <x><p> where name=123` as it is not entirely clear how the elements should be mapped. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim , I have modified the code for better understanding.Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious why you want to output the html as escaped (CDATA).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the xsl:output element at the top of the stylesheet to list the elements you need as CDATA, this way:

```
<xsl:output
method="xml" ...
cdata-section-elements="content"
/>
```

The attribute `cdata-section-elements` tells the XSLT processor that the element `content` must be written as a CDATA section.

Comment: thanks Bill!But my question was is it possible to achieve the scenario that i have mentined above using XSLT.